# Mysql query - round() function

Tags: mysql, sql

i want to ask, does exist some way to use selected value from leftjoin table, into round function as decimal parameter.

For example.:  `ROUND(sum(stats_bets_hourly.turnover_sum / currencies.rate ), 2) AS turnover_sum`

Should be: `ROUND(sum(stats_bets_hourly.turnover_sum / currencies.rate ), currencies.comma) AS turnover_sum`

Thanks and sorry for my english.

---

**UPDATE:**
Sorry that was badly formulated question. Round is working fine, but if currencies.comma value is 0 then query response is - 75312.000000, if currencies.comma value is 2, then - 75312.480000, if instead of currencies.comma i just writing 0 or 2 then i got - 75312 and 75312.48.

Comment: Er, what do you mean by "leftjoin table"? Is one of the two tables outer-joined? Even the currencies table? Then `currencies.rate` could be NULL, thus making the result for the currency NULL. (And `currencies.comma` = NULL would equally make the result NULL).

Comment: I've updated your request. You should not post updates as answers, but edit your request instead, just as I did now. Please delete your "answer".

Comment: 75312.480000 equals 75312.48, they are the same number, so both are correct. I assume that when using a literal 2, the DBMS knows that the resulting value will have no more than 2 decimal places and displays it accordingly. With a variable however the DBMS doesn't know beforehand which precision to expect, so it defaults to more decimal places. Anyhow, in my answer I told you that `ROUND` has nothing to do with how to *display* data, it is only a mathematical operation. You are looking for `FORMAT` instead, which you use to display a number in a desired format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, of course you can use a column instead of the numeric literal in ROUND.

That's easy to demonstrate:

```
select round(123.4567, pos) from (select 2 as pos) x;
```

In your case which is

```
ROUND(sum(stats_bets_hourly.turnover_sum / currencies.rate ), currencies.comma)
```

there must be just one `currencies.comma` value you are dealing with in your query (by having `currencies.comma` or `currencies.id` in your GROUP BY clause, or by limiting them in the WHERE clause.) If you are dealing with multiple `currencies.comma` values, then you probably need two steps, e.g.:

```
select
  sum(turnover_partsum) as turnover_sum
from
(
  select 
    c.comma,
    round(sum(sbh.turnover_sum / c.rate ), c.comma) AS turnover_partsum
  from currencies c
  join stats_bets_hourly sbh on ...
  group by c.comma
);
```

EDIT: Just one more thought on that: `currencies.comma` tells you how to *round* when doing calculations? That doesn't seem likely. Maybe you'd rather want to *display* a currency with the according number of decimal places. That would be `FORMAT` rather than `ROUND`:

```
format(sum(sbh.turnover_sum / c.rate ), c.comma)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do so as long as it is an integer number.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry that was badly formulated question. Round is working fine, but if currencies.comma value is 0 then query response is - 75312.000000, if   currencies.comma value is 2, then - 75312.480000,  if instead of currencies.comma i just writing 0 or 2 then i got - 75312 and 75312.48.

Comment: Format was a solution. T.y. horsten Kettner